# Break a column at regular intervals into multiple rows

Tags: r, split, rows

I have a column of numbers in a csv file and I want to break the column at regular intervals and transpose them into multiple rows. For example:

Dummy input file:

```
10
25  
09
04
14
100
01
10
100
04
04
01
04
```

Expected output (Breaking at regular intervals of 3):

```
10 25 09 
04 14 100
01 10 100
04 04 01
04
```

I am trying to do this in **R** by using `for` loop but haven't succeeded. I am not getting the desired output but also there are more than 10 million points like these in a single column. So I am not sure if using loop is an efficient way. I have googled and seen other such queries on stackexchange like [split string at regular intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948018/split-string-at-regular-intervals) and [How to split a string into substrings of a given length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619616/how-to-split-a-string-into-substrings-of-a-given-length). But it hasn't solved my problem.

Nevertheless, any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a dynamic `tidyverse` way. Should work for any breaks value.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data_frame(x = sample(20, 10))

breaks <- 3

df %>% 
  mutate(
    id = rep(paste0("col", 1:breaks), length.out = nrow(.)),
    rn = ave(x, id, FUN = seq_along)
  ) %>% 
  spread(id, x) %>% 
  select(-rn)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
   col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     6     8    11
2    16     4    14
3    15     9    19
4     1    NA    NA

# another example with breaks at 6
breaks <- 6

df %>% 
  mutate(
    id = rep(paste0("col", 1:breaks), length.out = nrow(.)),
    rn = ave(x, id, FUN = seq_along)
  ) %>% 
  spread(id, x) %>% 
  select(-rn)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     6     8    11    16     4    14
2    15     9    19     1    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks. It's almost working. I am encountering an error `Duplicate identifiers for rows (600, 653,...)` while working on the actual data. For small dummy data it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is your breaks > 26? If so,  you need to adjust the `letters[1:breaks]` to something more appropriate. Seems like you are breaking at intervals of 52. Also this question has been marked as duplicate so check out the original question for other answers.

Comment: Yes. Originally I am breaking at intervals of 11446. What modifications needs to be done with `letters[1:breaks]` ?

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it scalable to any breaks value. Try it and let me know.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one base R option.  We can pad your input vector/column with `NA` so that its length becomes a multiple of three.  Then, generate index series for each of three columns, and create the desired data frame.

```
rem <- length(input) %% 3
input <- c(input, rep(NA, ifelse(rem == 0, 0, 3 - rem)))
idx1 <- seq(1, length(input), 3)
idx2 <- seq(2, length(input), 3)
idx3 <- seq(3, length(input), 3)

df <- data.frame(v1=input[idx1], v2=input[idx2], v3=input[idx3])
```

Comment: Not for production use, but [here is a small demo](https://rextester.com/CNWC23750) showing that the logic works.

Comment: This works when we take the `input` file as a vector `c(1,2,..)`. However when I import a csv file containing these numbers it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dark_Knight Then my code would just require a slight modification.  We can replace `input` with the data frame/data table column.

Comment: `read.csv( "my_data.csv" )[ ,1 ]` would give you a vector

Comment: Elegant solution. But if `length(input)` is a very large number (millions) and the break needs to be done at intervals of magnitude thousand, then it won't be possible to generate `idx` sequences manually.

Comment: Yes, it would be, and a sequence in the millions should not be a problem at all in R.  Billions is another story...but...do you really have that much data?

Comment: Fortunately and unfortunately yes. I can't even open the csv file.

Comment: _Excel_ file?  What does that have to do with R?  Just read in the CSV file into R, and go from there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen got it. Thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What I meant to say earlier was that in place of 3 suppose I have to make the break at 1000. Then in that case do I need to manually create 1000 `idx` sequences like `idx1, idx2, ... , idx1000`?

Comment: @Dark_Knight Yes, for 1000 columns my solution is not so nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cut function in dplyr package.

```
dataframe %>% group_by(column) %>% 
mutate(new_variable = cut(column, breaks=quantile(column, c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), labels=F))
```

or

```
#breaks into the intervals you require 
new_variable <- cut(as.numeric(dataset$column),breaks = 3)
```

And then use melt function in reshape package to transpose column to rows

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in the form of a vector you can do the following:

```
data <- c('10', '25', '09', '04', '14', '100', '01',
          '10', '100', '04', '04', '01', '04')
split(data, ceiling(seq_along(data) / 3))
```

If it is in a data frame this should do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data <- data.frame(
  value = c('10', '25', '09', '04', '14', '100', '01',
        '10', '100', '04', '04', '01', '04'))
data %>%
  mutate(key = rep_len(c('a', 'b', 'c'), length.out = nrow(.))) %>%
  group_by(idx = as.integer((row_number() - 1) / 3)) %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-idx) %>%
  ungroup()
```