# Selecting two digits from a 4 or six digit number in R

Tags: regex, r, select, grepl

I have a matrix which includes 4 and six digit numbers, which basically comprise 2 or 3 pairs of digits, describing overlapping shapes. So, for example,

```
data1<-cbind(474440,470000,440000,40000,404400,474000).
```

Each cell of the matrix has either a `47`, a `44`, a `40`, or some combination of the above, and the rest of the number is zeros. I have another data set which is similar, but only has two pairs of numbers, not three. So, for example,

```
data2<-cbind(5253,5200,5300,50000,5053).
```

Again, this combination contains `52`,`53`,`50`, or some combination thereof. I would like to be able to select a logical matrix for each one of the two digit numbers, so selecting `40` in `data1` would yield `(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)`, and selecting `50` in `data2` would yield `(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)`. I have tried creating a list of the unique two digit numbers I'm looking for, and using grepl to select those that match the pattern, but because of the zeros that are in the matrix which represent empty values, grepl selects too many of the cells; for example, looking for `40` in `data1` would yield `(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)`.

Comment: I think you are making this too difficult on yourself. how about if you put delimiters between the pairs, such as "-" so that you dont get a false match? or replace the 00 values with xx?

Comment: This question about [splitting a string into substrings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619616/how-to-split-a-string-into-substrings-of-a-given-length) may be of use to you.

Comment: Warning: remember that the `grep, gsub` family of functions coerce numbers to characters. For example, `data<-474.4400e7; grepl('444',data)` will return `TRUE` (unless you've done something bad with `format`, as Sven hinted at).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I did originally use options (scipen) but format is obviously much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` with the correct regular expression. The function `format`
 is necessary to avoid scientific notation of numbers.

```
data1<-cbind(474440,470000,440000,400000,404400,474000)

grepl("^(..)*40", format(data1))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE


data2<-cbind(5253,5200,5300,5000,5053)

grepl("^(..)*50", format(data2))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

*How it works?*

In the regular expression `^(..)*40`, `^` is the beginning of the string. `(..)` is of group of two characters. The quantifier `*` means 0 or multiple times. The `40` just means literal `40`. Hence this matches `40` preceded by exactly zero, two, four etc. characters.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! And thanks for the very clear explanation. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
#   ...........      look for 40 in .......   split string into pairs
apply(data1,2,function(x)40 %in% strsplit(gsub("([[:alnum:]]{2})", "\\1 ", x), " ")[[1]])

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I figured there was a way to do this with some sort of string split function, but I couldn't quite get my head around it. Thanks for the suggestion.