# Substrings of whole string in R

Tags: r, substring

This type of question is already asked many times, however I could not get the answer according to my needs.

I know some way of splitting strings in `R`. If I have a string `x <- "AGCAGT"`, and want to split the string into characters of three. I would do this by

```
substring(x, seq(1, nchar(x)-1, 3), seq(3, nchar(x), 3))
```

and string of two character much faster by

```
split <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
substrg <- paste0(split[c(TRUE, FALSE)], split[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
```

As a new user of `R`, I feel difficulty to split string according to my requirements. If `x <- "AGCTG"` and if I use `substring(x, seq(1, nchar(x)-1, 3), seq(3, nchar(x), 3))`, I do not get the last two character substring. I get

```
"AGC" ""
```

However I am interested to get something like

```
"AGC" "TG"
```

or if I have `x <- "AGCT"` and splitting 3 characters at a time, I would like to get some thing like

```
"AGC" "T"`
```

I short, how to split  a string into substrings of desired length (2,3,4,5...n), and also retaining those remaining characters less than the desired length.

Comment: See the output of `seq(3, nchar(x), 3)`, which is the end of the substring and you'll get what the problem is.

Comment: It appears that there [there is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23262521/1655567) concerned with precisely the same problem.

Comment: The marked duplicate does not solve my problem. The answer by `zx8754`, however, later deleted seems to solve my problem

Comment: @zx8754 Please consider to undelete the post.  As per the OP's concerns, I am reopening the post.

Comment: @RichardScriven Please check my desired output above. Consider string `AGCGGCCAGCT`  and three character split.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for reopening the post. Indeed not a duplicate, some rushed to mark it as duplicate. The solution @zx8754 works perfect.   `x <- "AGCGGCCAGCTGCCTGAA"
mylen <- 5
ss <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
v1 <- sapply(split(ss, ceiling(seq_along(ss)/mylen)), paste, collapse = "")`

Comment: This is pretty confusing to follow as all solutions are comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution in a few simple steps.

```
x <- "AGCGGCCAGCTGCCTGAA"

# desired length
mylen = 5

# start indices
start <- seq(1, nchar(x), mylen)

# end indicies
end <- pmin(start + mylen - 1, nchar(x))

substring(x, start, end)
[1] "AGCGG" "CCAGC" "TGCCT" "GAA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by **zx8754**. But unfortunately he deleted the answer after some marked the question as duplicate. If he would like to post this as an answer, I'l delete my post.

```
x <- "AGCGGCCAGCTGCCTGAA"
mylen <- 5 
ss <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
sapply(split(ss, ceiling(seq_along(ss)/mylen)), paste, collapse = "")
```