# Split a string with a gap of two characters

Tags: r, string, performance, split, substring

I've wrote code that does this:

```
text <- "abcdef"

substring(text, first = (1:(nchar(text)/2)) * 2 - 1, last = (1:(nchar(text)/2)) * 2)
```

Result:

```
"ab" "cd" "ef"
```

It works perfecty for small sized Strings but not for long ones.

Any suggestion, how I can do it faster?

Comment: What do you mean with "but not for long". Please give an example!

Comment: @jogo I've got a file with a huge length String. Just imagine a whole book for example

Comment: For efficiency, see "g2" solution by @GSee [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11619681/680068).

Comment: @zx8754 fastest way is:

`sst <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
out <- paste0(sst[c(TRUE, FALSE)], sst[c(FALSE, TRUE)])`

Comment: That is why I posted **the** link.

Comment: @jogo it is duplicate of another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619616/how-to-split-a-string-into-substrings-of-a-given-length/11619681#11619681)

Comment: @zx8754 yes, your comment was very helpful

Comment: Glad it was helpful, I now updated the duplicate links to your post.

Comment: @Yuva I not voted "dup". I voted "why this code is not working ..."

Comment: @jogo the previous code works but is not optimal

Comment: @zx8754 it's a shame that i can't mark your comment as the accepted answer

Comment: No need, anyone having the same question, can easily navigate to linked posts and get the answer. Or @ANG could add that solution to their post, then you could accept as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `trimws(gsub("(.{2})", "\\1 ", text))` and 
`stringi::stri_sub(text, seq(1, stringi::stri_length(text), by = 2), length = 2`)

Comment: Would you please add your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619616/how-to-split-a-string-into-substrings-of-a-given-length/11619681#11619681) so I can declare your answer as the accepted one? Otherwise, if people get here and see that it's a duplicate, they may not have a look at what you said as it's in the bottom of the windows