# Split a sequence of numbers into groups of 10 digits using R

Tags: r

I would like for R to read in the first 10,000 digits of Pi and group every 10 digits together

e.g., I want R to read in a sequence

```
pi <- 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097...
```

and would like R to give me a table where each row contains 10 digit:

3141592653

5897932384

6264338327
...

I am new to R and really don't know where to start so any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619616/how-to-split-a-string-into-substrings-of-a-given-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://rextester.com/OQRM27791

```
p <- strsplit("314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097", "")
digits <- p[[1]]

split(digits, ceiling((1:length(digits)) / 10));
```

Comment: Nice answer. I think you're missing the final stage of pasting the digits back together into length-10 strings and unlisting the result, but that should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. It's fully reproducible, so just cut and paste it into your R console. The vector `result` is the first 10,000 digits of pi, split into 1000 strings of 10 digits.

For this many digits, I have used an online source for the precalculated value of pi. This is read in using `readChar` and the decimal point is stripped out with `gsub`. The resulting string is split into individual characters and put in a 1000 * 10 matrix (filled row-wise). The rows are then `paste`d into strings, giving the result. I have displayed only the first 100 entries of `result` for clarity of presentation.

```r
pi_url  <- "https://www.pi2e.ch/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/pi_dec_1m.txt"
pi_char <- gsub("\\.", "", readChar(url, 1e4 + 1))
pi_mat  <- matrix(strsplit(pi_char, "")[[1]], byrow = TRUE, ncol = 10)
result  <- apply(pi_mat, 1, paste0, collapse = "")

head(result, 100)
#>   [1] "3141592653" "5897932384" "6264338327" "9502884197" "1693993751"
#>   [6] "0582097494" "4592307816" "4062862089" "9862803482" "5342117067"
#>  [11] "9821480865" "1328230664" "7093844609" "5505822317" "2535940812"
#>  [16] "8481117450" "2841027019" "3852110555" "9644622948" "9549303819"
#>  [21] "6442881097" "5665933446" "1284756482" "3378678316" "5271201909"
#>  [26] "1456485669" "2346034861" "0454326648" "2133936072" "6024914127"
#>  [31] "3724587006" "6063155881" "7488152092" "0962829254" "0917153643"
#>  [36] "6789259036" "0011330530" "5488204665" "2138414695" "1941511609"
#>  [41] "4330572703" "6575959195" "3092186117" "3819326117" "9310511854"
#>  [46] "8074462379" "9627495673" "5188575272" "4891227938" "1830119491"
#>  [51] "2983367336" "2440656643" "0860213949" "4639522473" "7190702179"
#>  [56] "8609437027" "7053921717" "6293176752" "3846748184" "6766940513"
#>  [61] "2000568127" "1452635608" "2778577134" "2757789609" "1736371787"
#>  [66] "2146844090" "1224953430" "1465495853" "7105079227" "9689258923"
#>  [71] "5420199561" "1212902196" "0864034418" "1598136297" "7477130996"
#>  [76] "0518707211" "3499999983" "7297804995" "1059731732" "8160963185"
#>  [81] "9502445945" "5346908302" "6425223082" "5334468503" "5261931188"
#>  [86] "1710100031" "3783875288" "6587533208" "3814206171" "7766914730"
#>  [91] "3598253490" "4287554687" "3115956286" "3882353787" "5937519577"
#>  [96] "8185778053" "2171226806" "6130019278" "7661119590" "9216420198"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`:

```
pi  <- readLines("https://www.pi2e.ch/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/pi_dec_1m.txt")

library(stringr)
t <- unlist(str_extract_all(sub("\\.","", pi), "\\d{10}"))
t[1:100]
  [1] "3141592653" "5897932384" "6264338327" "9502884197" "1693993751" "0582097494" "4592307816" "4062862089"
  [9] "9862803482" "5342117067" "9821480865" "1328230664" "7093844609" "5505822317" "2535940812" "8481117450"
 [17] "2841027019" "3852110555" "9644622948" "9549303819" "6442881097" "5665933446" "1284756482" "3378678316"
 [25] "5271201909" "1456485669" "2346034861" "0454326648" "2133936072" "6024914127" "3724587006" "6063155881"
 [33] "7488152092" "0962829254" "0917153643" "6789259036" "0011330530" "5488204665" "2138414695" "1941511609"
 [41] "4330572703" "6575959195" "3092186117" "3819326117" "9310511854" "8074462379" "9627495673" "5188575272"
 [49] "4891227938" "1830119491" "2983367336" "2440656643" "0860213949" "4639522473" "7190702179" "8609437027"
 [57] "7053921717" "6293176752" "3846748184" "6766940513" "2000568127" "1452635608" "2778577134" "2757789609"
 [65] "1736371787" "2146844090" "1224953430" "1465495853" "7105079227" "9689258923" "5420199561" "1212902196"
 [73] "0864034418" "1598136297" "7477130996" "0518707211" "3499999983" "7297804995" "1059731732" "8160963185"
 [81] "9502445945" "5346908302" "6425223082" "5334468503" "5261931188" "1710100031" "3783875288" "6587533208"
 [89] "3814206171" "7766914730" "3598253490" "4287554687" "3115956286" "3882353787" "5937519577" "8185778053"
 [97] "2171226806" "6130019278" "7661119590" "9216420198"
```